# Why is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on this problem. I have checked on wolfram alpha, and the calculator says that this series is divergent. However, I can't find a way to prove it.

The problem:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}$$

So I tried doing this problem with the direct comparison test.

I have concluded that

$$
\frac{n^2}{n^3} >\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}
$$
$$
b_{n}> a_{n}
$$

$b_{n}$ is a p-series, where p=1. This means that the series $b_{n}$ is divergent, making the test direct comparison test inconclusive.
$$
\frac{n^2}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n}
$$

I appreciate any help... thanks! :)

Comment: It's divergent.

Comment: @ Botnakov N. - that’s the best comeback I’ve heard all week.

Comment: Sorry, my question was wrong, I don't quite understand why it diverges, since if Bn diverges it doesn't mean that An will diverge too if Bn > An > 0

Comment: becasuse is equivalent to series $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Show that for large $n$ you have $a_n \ge c {1 \over n}$ for some constant $c>0$.

Comment: @copper.hat how can that prove that $a_{n}$ is divergent?

Comment: The series $\sum_n {1 \over n}$ is divergent, so by comparison we have $\sum_{n \ge N} a_n \ge c \sum_{n \ge N} {1 \over n}$.

Comment: Another way is to write $$ \frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{n-1}{n^2-n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1/(n-1)}\ge\frac{1}{n+1} $$ or you can do the whole "add and subtract $1/n$" trick.

Comment: I understand that series $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent. What bugs me is the following, in the comparison test $b_{n}\geq a_{n}>0$. Then if $b_{n}$ converges then $a_{n}$ converges too. And if $a_{n}$ diverges then $b_{n}$ diverges too. Since in the case of my problem,  $b_{n}$ is divergent and I am not sure how to prove that $a_{n}$ is divergent too. Sorry if I am unclear :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1} \geq \frac{n^2 - \frac{n^2}{2}}{n^3+n^3} =  \frac{1}{4}\frac{n^2}{n^3}  =\frac{1}{4n}. $$

Comment: I'm trying my best to understand. Why did you add $\frac{-n^2}{2} $ to the numerator and $n^3$ to the denominator?

Comment: If you reduce the numerator, you get something smaller.  If you increase the denominator, you get something smaller.  If you do both, you get something smaller.

Comment: I understand. But in which way can that help us prove that the original sequence is divergent? @saulspatz

Comment: What's 1/4 of infinity?

Comment: 1/4 is insignificant since infinity is an infinitely large number?

Comment: @galaxyworks Technically  no, because infinity isn't a number. Non-technically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1} = \frac{n^2+1 -2}{n^3+1} = \frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1} -\frac{2}{n^3+1} \geq \frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n^3+1} \quad \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1} -\frac{2}{n^3+1}\right)\\
\\
= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1}\ -\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^3+1} \\
\\
\geq \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\right)\ -\ L \\
\end{align}

for some $L\in \mathbb{R}.$